# How to make click event on "All" option to select all data from all the category in the following code

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Actually, I have gone through a lot of google pages, but didn't able to get to the exact point. I am retrieving the option from the database and it works fine for other option coming from database. Now i want to show all data items(i.e. all data from all category) when **All** option is selected.
This is my HTML to select Category

```
<div class="input-label">
        Filter by:
       </div>
            <select name="selectCategory" ng-init="option[1]" ng-options="option.CategoryName for option in CategoryList.availableOptions track by option.RecordId" id="selectCategory" ng-model="CategoryList.selectedOption" 
            ng-change="fnSelectCategory()"> <option value="">--All--</option>      
            </select>
       </label>
```

This is my AngularJS code to bind to view model

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])
.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope,$http,$state) {
$scope.CategoryList={
  availableOptions: [    
  ],
  selectedOption: {RecordId: '', CategoryName: ''}
}
$scope.customerView=[];
 $http.get("http://iwantall.azurewebsites.net/api/customer/allList")
.then(function(response)
{ 
 $scope.CategoryList.availableOptions= response.data.categoryViewModel; 
 $scope.customerView = response.data.itemListViewModel;     
});
$scope.fnSelectCategory=function(){

 $http({
 url:"http://iwantall.azurewebsites.net/api/customer/selectByCategory", 
method: "POST",
params: {categoryId:$scope.CategoryList.selectedOption.RecordId}
}).then(function(response)
{
$scope.customerView = response.data; 
})
```

This is my html to display Items

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="item in customerView" 
              item="item"
              href="#/tab/detail/{{item.CategoryId}}" class="item-remove-animate" ng-controller='detailController' ng-click="fnDetailView(item)">
             <h2>{{ item.Description }}</h2>
             <h4>Category: {{item.RelatedCategory}}</h4>
             <h4 style='font-style:italic'>posted on:</h4> <h5>{{item.PostedOn}}</h5>      
    </ion-item>
```

Comment: Once the category is selected, where are you displaying the items? Are you using `ng-repeat`? Can you post more of your html code?

Comment: yes, i am using ng-repeat and refreshing the view on selecting the category.

Answer (score 1):

You could add your `All` category to your `CategoryList.availableOptions`. That way you're only dealing with one object, instead of having to add an `<option>` element in your `<select>`. Then when you select an option, you will be able to reference its value to be able to do something, like show all data. Take a look at the snippet below to see the idea behind it. Let me know if it's confusing.

```js
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic'])

.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
   
  $scope.getListFromRequest = function() {
    $scope.response = [{id: 1, Option: "Option 1"},
                       {id: 2, Option: "Option 2"},
                       {id: 3, Option: "Option 3"}
                      ];
    return $scope.response;
  }

  $scope.addAll = function() { 
    $scope.list = $scope.getListFromRequest();
     $scope.list.push({id: 0, Option: "--All--"});
  };
  
  $scope.fnSelectCategory = function(value) {
    alert(value.Option);
  };
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="ionicApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    
    <title>Ionic Template</title>

    <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.2/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.2/js/ionic.bundle.js">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    
    <ion-content padding="true">
<div>
  <button class="button button-positive" ng-click="addAll()">Add Categories</button>
   </div>
      </br>
  <div>
      <label>
     Filter by:
  <select ng-init="selected = getListFromRequest[0]" ng-model=selected ng-options="option as option.Option for option in list track by option.id" ng-change="fnSelectCategory(selected)" 
           ></select>
  </label>
      </div>
    </ion-content>
  </body>
</html>
```